# fatal: bad config line 3 in file C:/Users/hp Probook 450 G2/.gitconfig

Tags: git, installation, fatal-error

git can't get recognized by my vscode saying i should i install when its already installed, then i tried calling it up using CMD and this is the error am getting "[fatal: bad config line 3 in file C:/Users/hp Probook 450 G2/.gitconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7HfU.png)

when i open git.config with vs code, this is what am getting and line three is just a configuration of my name "[git.config open in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQulP.png)"

all i wanted was to install git and start making repos, please help.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  Instead, copy the text and paste it as a code block.  Pictures can't be searched and they aren't accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `.gitconfig` contains shell commands on lines 3 and 4.  Those are not valid in a `.gitconfig` and should be removed.

If you want those lines to have effect, then you can paste them (without the leading `$`) into a Git Bash window.  Using `git-config` will edit the `.gitconfig` on your behalf so that it's always syntactically valid and this kind of problem doesn't happen again.

Comment: so after understanding the purpose of .gitconfig and how it stays in the system even after uninstalling git, I decided to delete it, reinstall git and then try to configure my name and email in vs code again, am just learning code so it took me some time to understand that i should remove the "$" sign from both lines and just after doing it, voila, all my changes to the project were pending to commit, was so happy that I got upset realizing you had responded with the very instructions I needed but only to see the comment after struggling for so long, experience is the best teacher anyway.

Comment: waited a few minutes before losing faith in this platform to having generous people like you, thank you so much....